# Setting up signatures with different font in Mail.app

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, signature

I am trying to set up signature blocks to attach to emails sent using mac mail.  I want part of the signature block to be in script, but using the font option I cannot get it to a script.

Comment: which script- font name ?

Comment: Bear in mind that your recipients will not display your "custom" font if they do not have it installed on their computer.  So it is best to choose one that all computers have installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

The font option only lets you select your default font. To select any font, when in the Signature editor, press ⌘T to open the Fonts inspector and choose a font family and typeface.

[image]